# How to edit / how to format box overlapping with footer when scrolling down

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, footer, sidebar

I just edited an answer on Unix&Linux and when scrolling down, the semi-transparent right sidebar boxes "How to edit" and "How to format" kept their fixed positioning and overlapped with the page footer.

[image]

While posting this, I have seen several (not) duplicate questions about this issue, and although from my personal taste, I would prefer the boxes to stop scrolling before the footer is reached, I can accept the development teams decision to let it overlap.

However, on all those other posts, the boxes had an opaque background, so that the footer was hidden and the box content was readable. Here the boxes are transparent though, so the texts get mixed and are no longer well readable.

Comment: The box isn't transparent. The issue is that the footer is in front of the sidebar instead of behind. This also happens here, when you [ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), so it's not just a problem with U&L or editing.

Comment: Also reported on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351124/similar-question-sidebar-z-index-issue

Comment: This appears to be fixed now, can you please verify? /cc @rene

Comment: Looks fixed, but I have reported the issue from a different system than I used to verify it now. Will verify it there as well later, but I expect it to be fixed. Thanks @ShadowWizard

Comment: This is not fixed. I'm seeing the problem right now...

Comment: @gbianchi I think you should comment that below the answer by Pawel, who is the SE employee that reported the bug as solved. Here probably only I will be notified and I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks again for reporting - it is now fixed on production. There was some issue with `z-index`. Help box now overlays footer as expected.

Comment: Cheers, and enjoy the rep boost! ;)

Comment: whooop whoooop!

Comment: [Someone commented below the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297223/how-to-edit-how-to-format-box-overlapping-with-footer-when-scrolling-down?noredirect=1#comment972040_297223) and claims that the issue is not solved yet. I don't know any details, just wanted to forward the message.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing it but in a different way. Maybe is the way you want to show it, but is still overflowing down there. It has to overlay the footer? not stop before the footer?