# Missing padding in error messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, error-message

Something happened to the padding of the various error messages we get, e.g. error "You have already voted to delete":

> [image]

Can the padding please be brought back?

Comment: thanks for reporting - will take a look

Comment: @Paweł thanks! While at it, can you please also take a look on [this other bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297223/how-to-edit-how-to-format-box-overlapping-with-footer-when-scrolling-down)? Think it's also result of some recent CSS change you made. (Maybe not you in person, I mean the design team. :))

Comment: Cross-site duplication in [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351360/2451726).

Comment: @Arulkumar well, it happens on all sites, so the fitting place to report is here on MSE.

Comment: Yes, I just linked the MSO question here to get attention to the design team.

Comment: @Arulkumar the design team is already working on a fix, see the tag and Paweł's comment.

Comment: Saw the details, but the other question was not noticed, after linked here now it is consider by the team.

Comment: @Arulkumar sorry I don't follow. This is the same bug. Fixing it here will also fix it across the whole network.

Comment: @Paweł I see both are fixed, can you please add the completed tags to the bug reports, possibly writing answers on both? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks again for reporting - it is now fixed on production.