# Alignment of votes in Election

Tags: bug, design, election

I have elected 3 users in [The Workplace election](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election).
The votes I casted are shown below the **Election Phase** tab.

[image]

---

Then they stand still in the right, even when I scroll down.

[image]

---

But they stand still even when the end of the border is reached. This makes it to overlap the contents below the border.

[image]

---

Can this be fixed? When the page is zoomed in, the overlap looks worse

Comment: This is as intended: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297223/how-to-edit-how-to-format-box-overlapping-with-footer-when-scrolling-down

Comment: Yep, thanks for that. It's marked as status-completed but the problem is still there

Comment: No the problem there was that the background of the box was transparent. That the box overflows the footer is a deliberate design choice, so this is [status-by-design], not a bug.